# React Router RouteParams in history

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am using react 17.0.2 and have defined routes like this:

```
export const PATH = {
  editProduct: '/edit-product/:productId'
}
export const routes = [
  {
    path: PATH.editProduct,
    render: (props) => <Product {...props}/>
  }
]
export const useRoutes = () => ({ PATH, routes });
```

The routes are then used with 'react-router-dom' version: ^5.2.0

Some previous paths without routeparams uses `history.push(PATH.somePath);` and it works, but I would like to use the react routerParams in some component.

Like:

```
history.push({pathname: PATH.editProduct, routerParam: {productId: "2"} });
```

Previous paths with routeparams have been passed by not using PATH variable, but instead typing the string like `history.push('/edit-product/' + productId);` I would want to reuse the PATH variables, but I can't figure out how it could be achieved smartly.

If I use PATH.editProduct in history.push method, it places the routeparam along with it like /edit-product/:productId, which is not the behaviour I am looking for. Is there parsing method in history for routeparams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `generatePath` util in `react-router-dom`.

```
import { generatePath } from "react-router-dom";

const path = generatePath(PATH.editProduct, {
  productId: 1
});

history.push(path);
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath